# Удаление предыдущих событий jQuery

Tags: jquery, input, javascript, html5

Ребят нужна помощь

Вот код: http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/8627/

При клике на кнопку добавляется input,  мне нужно чтобы при клике на следующую кнопку, все предыдущие добавленые input удалялись и добавлялся  новый input который соответствует данной кнопки.

Цель чтобы чтобы при клике на любую из трех кнопок, на странице был только один input, добавленный последней нажатой кнопкой.

Answer (score 1):

$input персонализируете по желанию, prepend будет не клонировать элемент а именно перемещать, работает при условии уникальности вставляемого контента.

```
$(function() {
        $input = $('<input type="text" size="20" name="demo">');
        $('.btn-paket').on('click', function(e){
            $input.attr('value', $(e.target).attr('id'));
            $('#wrapForm').prepend($input);
        });               
    });
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/8668/](http://jsfiddle.net/Ridzhi/tZPg4/8668/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {
$('h2 a').live('click', function () {
    var value = $(this).attr('id');
    var input = '<input type="text" size="20" name="demo" value="' + value  +'"><br>';
    if ($('#wrapForm input:first').attr('id') !== 'p_scnt') {
        $('#wrapForm input:first, #wrapForm br:first').remove();
    }
    $('#wrapForm').prepend(input);
});
```

});

http://jsfiddle.net/tZPg4/8667/

Comment: live ?? ....

Comment: @eicto, в фидле ТС выставлен jquery 1.4, возможно это и побудило отвечающего таким несовременностям.

Comment: да всё равно, не надо учить плохому., ваш же код в  1.4.3 легко адаптируется... (on на click поменять)

Answer (score 0):

Решил менять не input,  а только значение value=""

Вот решение: http://jsfiddle.net/iiil/tZPg4/8676/

но всё равно всем спасибо